# Trying to identify Late Night Bad Sci-Fi Movie

Tags: story-identification, movie

Trying to identify a real bad sci-fi movie that aired on Comet TV. Maybe from the 1990s. Filmed at a school or college campus, possibly during the summer. Main character was the brother of the villain who was born in outer space. Their mother was a scientist. The villain  screamed in the ears of others and walked around shirtless. When he screamed into their ears, they became under his control. The main character could tell if someone was mind-controlled if they had blood running down their ear. I also think the villain could communicate with aliens because he was born in outer space.